# Sun Fire V40z, big gap between memory reported by dmidecode and what the Linux kernel sees

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, dmidecode

I'm looking after a V40z (a loaner), running RHEL 4.8 (no, I can't update it, it's a loaner) that according to dmidecode has 8 DIMMs of 2048M each, which makes for 16GB RAM as far as I'm concerned.

The kernel, however, reports the total memory to be

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:     14898844 kB
```

Now, on machines with integrated graphics chip-sets I've seen memory in the range of 128 to 512MB go "missing", but what would be an explanation for this huge discrepancy on a server? The way I see it it's missing 1.8G.